# Proper way to select statistically random dataset for cotraining in matlab

Tags: matlab, statistics, machine-learning, classification

I have came across various ways to find out random dataset for training of a classifier in MATLAB like `crossval` and  `cvpartition` etc. I have gone through all the examples but couldn't understand them properly. I want to do the following:

1. I have to randomly divide dataset into training and test dataset
2. Then among the training set I need to randomly select 2 data points (labelled data for those who are familiar with co-training.)
3. At last I need to obtain average accuracy obtained from the classifier.

Edit: My dataset looks something like this:

> 0.1 0.2 0.2 1 22 40
>   0.0 0.1 0.3 0 33 30
>   0.5 0.5 0.5 1 10 11

and so on

This dataset is very similar with 40 rows and 70 columns

Comment: Please provide a small example dataset at the very least.

Comment: @RoneyMichael I have provided a small example how my dataset looks. It's a numeric matrix of `40*70`.

Comment: Are there any constraints on the sizes of the training and test data-sets?

Comment: @RoneyMichael  Generally speaking standard 70:30 ratio of training and test dataset

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, each row of yours represents a particular record. If so, you could try something like this:

```
>> training_data = my_dataset(randsample(40,ceil(0.3*40)),:);
>> test_data = my_dataset(setdiff(1:40,randsample(40,ceil(0.3*40))),:);
>> two_points = training_data(randsample(ceil(0.3*40),2),:);
```

Comment: I understood you answer but everytime I will run it I will get a different result. I want average result out of all possible combination, like in `crossval`.

Comment: I'm sorry, but why can you not use `crossval` itself?

Comment: I do not know exactly how to use it in this context. I can use it for averaging over all combinations of test/train data but I have to choose two points for co training.I don't know how to do that,